# How to create a library that does something on a regular timer?

Tags: c#

I want to create a .Net library that does some background activity on a regular schedule (e.g. every hour). For sake of example, let's just say it retrieves the contents of a web page every hour and caches the content locally in a string. I then want to expose a public interface for consumers of the library that has a simple method which retrieves the cached string.

Effectively the consumers of the library do not need to know anything about the internal workings of how the string is retrieved.

Ideally, I want the library to agnostic to who it is consumed. E.g. it could be a console app, or web service or even another library.

What mechanism or class can I use in the library to allow me to carry out this background work to refresh the data?

Comment: You can create a service. You can create a normal console application and schedule a task to run the console once per hour. You can use a jobs library such as hangfire.

Comment: `while (true) Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromHours(1));` should work just fine

Comment: I want to create a library that does this in the background. I want the consumer of the library to be unaware that the background work is going on.

Comment: Like the classic [System.Timers.Timer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timers.timer)?

Comment: If you don't need to compatible with old .NET version, maybe you can consider the new [System.Threading.PeriodicTimer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.periodictimer).